# Does Android Studio not recognize encrypted phones?

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently encrypted my phone and Android Studio isn't registering it as connected any more. My computer still sees it, and says that it is even connected.

So I was wondering if this was the problem, or should I try other things to get Android Studio to register that my phone is plugged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to configure your phone to be developer mode first. It's not about Android Studio, it's about the privilege.

Go to Settings -> About Phone, tap Build Number quickly for 7 times (I know it sounds stupid), and there will be another option, Developer Options, popping up in the menu.

Choose it and turn Developer mode on, and turn "Enable USB Debugging" on.

This will give your IDE privilege to run code on your phone. Menu and step may vary slightly according to phone brand. The above steps are for Samsung S8, I've used other phones as well, it's basically the same. If you cannot find the options, just google "YOU_PHONE_TYPE how to enable USB debuging".